# How to add google map marker?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

In this code i need to add google map marker. i tried to much but don't know how to add map marker. If any one know please guide me.

```
// This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
// parameter when you first load the API. For example:
// <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

  function initMap() {
    var origin_place_id = null;
    var destination_place_id = null;
    var travel_mode = google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING;
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      mapTypeControl: false,
      center: {lat: 30.3753, lng: 69.3451},
      zoom: 7
    });
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('go'), 'click',route);
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
    var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
        position:map,
    });
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    marker.setMap(map);

    var origin_input = document.getElementById('origin-input');
    var destination_input = document.getElementById('destination-input');
    var modes = document.getElementById('mode-selector');


    //map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(origin_input);
    //map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(destination_input);
    //map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(go);
    //map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(modes);

    var origin_autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(origin_input);
    origin_autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
    var destination_autocomplete =
        new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(destination_input);
    destination_autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

    // Sets a listener on a radio button to change the filter type on Places
    // Autocomplete.
    function setupClickListener(id, mode) {
      var radioButton = document.getElementById(id);
      radioButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        travel_mode = mode;
      });
    }
    setupClickListener('changemode-walking', google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING);
    setupClickListener('changemode-transit', google.maps.TravelMode.TRANSIT);
    setupClickListener('changemode-driving', google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING);


    function expandViewportToFitPlace(map, place) {
        if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
      } else {
        map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
        map.setZoom(17);
      }
    }

    origin_autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
      var place = origin_autocomplete.getPlace();
      if (!place.geometry) {
        window.alert("Autocomplete's returned place contains no geometry");
        return;
      }
      expandViewportToFitPlace(map, place);

      // If the place has a geometry, store its place ID and route if we have
      // the other place ID
      origin_place_id = place.place_id;
      route(origin_place_id, destination_place_id, travel_mode,
            directionsService, directionsDisplay);
    });

    destination_autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
      var place = destination_autocomplete.getPlace();
      if (!place.geometry) {
        window.alert("Autocomplete's returned place contains no geometry");
        return;
      }

      expandViewportToFitPlace(map, place);
    $('#go').click(function(){
        var origin_input = document.getElementById('origin-input').value;
        var res = origin_input.split(",");
        var bc = res[0];
        var destination_input = document.getElementById('destination-input').value;
        var res = destination_input.split(",");
        var bd = res[0];
        //alert(bc);
        //alert(bd);
        //sessionStorage.setItem ("fromCity" , bc[0]);
        //sessionStorage.setItem ("toCity" , bd[0]);
      // If the place has a geometry, store its place ID and route if we have
      // the other place ID
        destination_place_id = place.place_id;
        route(origin_place_id, destination_place_id, travel_mode,
            directionsService, directionsDisplay);
        });
    });
    $('#mode-selector').hide();
    $('#go').click(function(){
        //$('#go').hide(250);
        $('#mode-selector').show(250);
    });


    function route(origin_place_id, destination_place_id, travel_mode,
                   directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
      if (!origin_place_id || !destination_place_id) {
        return;
      }
      directionsService.route({
        origin: {'placeId': origin_place_id},
        destination: {'placeId': destination_place_id},
        travelMode: travel_mode
      }, 
    function(response, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
          directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        } else {
          window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
        }
      });
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    }
  }
```

Comment: See if the tutorial helps.. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple 
Also, I noticed, the 'position' attribute in your marker code is set to 'map'

    `var marker=new google.maps.Marker({ position:map, });` 

It should rather be a lat-lon value.

Comment: I already see this tutorial but failed to know how to add map marker with my code example??

Comment: Try tracking the errors in the javascript console, also, check your position attribute value in the marker object being created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just follow the guides in the [Markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#add) of Google JavaScript API.

It's stated here that `google.maps.Marker` constructor takes a single Marker options object literal, specifying the initial properties of the marker.

The following fields are particularly important and commonly set when constructing a marker:

- `position` (required) specifies a LatLng identifying the initial location of the marker.
- `map` (optional) specifies the `Map` on which to place the marker. If you do not specify the map on construction of the marker, the marker is created but is not attached to (or displayed on) the map. You may add the marker later by calling the marker's `setMap()` method.

Check the above link to view the example code on how to add markers.

Also, Here is the code that I do to the sample code that you link as an example.

```
function initMap() {
var myLatLng = {lat: 30.3753, lng: 69.3451};
var origin_place_id = null;
var destination_place_id = null;
var travel_mode = google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING;
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
mapTypeControl: false,
zoom: 13,
center: myLatLng
});

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: myLatLng,
map: map,
});

var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you get your `map` variable outside the function for readability purpose.

```
var map;

function initMap() {
    var origin_place_id = null;
    var destination_place_id = null;
    var travel_mode = google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING;
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        mapTypeControl: false,
        center: {
            lat: 30.3753,
            lng: 69.3451
        },
        zoom: 7
    });
    ..... rest of your code
}
```

And you can add markers by,

```
function addMarker(lat, lng, title) {
  return new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {lat: lat, lng: lng};
    map: map,
    title: title
  });
}

var marker = addMarker(-50, 50, 'My Marker!!');
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-directions                            Please see this example in google sample map. I am using this in my project. I try the following code you give me but still failed to put marker on map.